# Why do irreducible polynomials of degree n over $\mathbb{F}_{2}$ need to divide $x^{2^n-1} - 1$ in order to be primitive?

Tags: group-theory

At the moment i am trying to understand primitive polynomials. Considering $p(x)$ to be irreducible I know that a root $a$ of $p(x)$ has to generate the multiplicative group of $\mathbb F_{2^n} = \mathbb Z_2[x] / p(x)$ in order for $p(x)$ to be primitive.
I am wondering about a different criteria I also read about which states that irreducible polynomials of degree n over $\mathbb{F}_{2}$ need to divide $x^{2^n-1} - 1$ in order to be primitive. Maybe someone could explain this to me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: How can an element of $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ divide an element of $\mathbb{Z}$? What does that mean?

Comment: You are completely right. I forgot to put the term $2^n$ into the exponent of x, I am sorry.

Comment: $x^{2^n} - 1 = (x + 1)^{2^n}$. You mean $x^{2^n} - x$. Or in general, $x^{p^n} - x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few facts:

- $\mathbb F_{p^n}^\times$ is cyclic (and has $p^n - 1$ elements)
- therefore every element of $\mathbb F_{p^n}^\times$ satisfies $\alpha^{p^{n}-1} = 1$ and $\alpha^{p^{n}} = \alpha$
- therefore there are $p^n$ distinct elements of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ which satisfy $\alpha^{p^n} = \alpha$
- therefore $x^{p^n} - x$ splits over $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$
- therefore the minimal polynomial of every element of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ is a factor of $x^{p^n} - x$
- therefore if $\alpha$ is a primitive root and $\mathbb{F}_p[\alpha] = \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ then the minimal polynomial has degree $[\mathbb{F}_{p^n} : \mathbb F_p] = n$ and is an irreducible factor of $x^{p^n} -x$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sadly I don't quite understand yet. In Wiki stands "An irreducible polynomial $F(x)$ of degree m over $GF(p)$, where p is prime, is a primitive polynomial if the smallest positive integer n such that $F(x)$ divides $x^n − 1$ is $n = p^m − 1$."
The facts you stated don't help to to understand this quote. Maybe you could elaborate a bit more? Anyway, thank you very much

Comment: @Flo work backwards for the converse. The smallest $n$ such that the minimal polynomial is a factor of $x^{p^n} - x$ is the smallest $n$ such $\alpha \in \mathbb F_{p^n}$ and is the smallest $n$ such that $\alpha$ satisfies the equation $\alpha^{p^n} = \alpha$.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me out! Sadly I can't upvote your answer due to my by now low reputation